# How to write script in console in making chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, html, google-chrome-extension

I have a js code which i run using chrome console,, but now i want to make a extension to use this code,, I made a simple html form with 2 buttons, I want that
When I will click on button the js code will run just like i do in chrome console.

I called the button using this code

```
$(function(){
    $('#rjct').click(function(){
        var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('_42ft _4jy0 _4jy3 _517h _51sy');

        for(var i = 0; i <= buttons.length; i++)  
               buttons[i].click();
    })
});
```

Where rjct is the id name of button.

And this is the image of the extension 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCbPz.png)

I edited the manifest.json like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJCk4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the [Getting Started Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted)

In short, what you'll need to do is to set your `manifest.json` file to have content_scripts point to your file, and mark which websites you want the extension to run on. For example, if you wanted your extension to run on stackoverflow.com, you would do something like this:

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://stackoverflow.com/*",
        "*://*.stackoverflow.com/*"
      ],
      "js": ["my_bundle.js"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
],
```

And then you would put your code inside of `my_bundle.js`.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your reply, 
i added this code in manifest.json, it is still nothing working when i click on button.
Please look at this screenshot, is it ok ? 
As i am new in javascript but i need this extension.

Comment: @SabbirHossain please edit your original question with the code that you're using along with the specific issue you're having

Comment: I edited the question and added the screenshot of my edited code according to your instructions.